# Start mysql replication server with '--skip-slave-start'

Tags: mysql, database, centos, replication

I tried to start mysql in slave host like below as mentioned in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-gtids-howto.html . But its not working

`$sudo systemctl mysqld --skip-slave-start`

Could someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By specifying:

```
$sudo systemctl mysqld --skip-slave-start
```

you are not passing any parameters to mysql but rather to systemctl. To add the parameter to mysqld, you will need to change the systemd.service file.

If the service file is in /etc/systemd/service, you can change this file directly by using:

```
systemctl edit mysqld.service
```

and then adding

```
--skip-slave-start
```

to the ExecStart line

If the mysqld.service file is in /usr/lib/systemd/system, then you can edit is directly as outlined above and then issue:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```